# Separate Users Across 2 Tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm building a Ruby on Rails application, I'm separating two sets of users:

- Buyers
- Sellers

Currently someone built the database with both under a Users table with:

```
t.string "user_type",    default: "buyer", null: false
```

There are some additional data I will need to hold for **Sellers** and there is also a few features/pages I want **Sellers** to have access to, but not **Buyers**.

For example I want to hold bank details so I can pay **Sellers** what we are paid by **Buyers** (we hold payments for a few days to ensure safe transaction). So the additional data may be:

- Account Number
- Sort Code

We do not need to store this data for **Buyers** since they use Stripe for payment.

Do we include the data on the current Users table? or do we create a new **Sellers** table that is linked to the Users table?

Comment: I wonder why the author of the original code didn't use Single Table Inheritance and performed it by hand instead...

Comment: I am unsure, what would you recommend? I'm guessing using Single Table inheritance. Is there any reason the person would not have used it? Thanks for your input @D-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one table and have the differences in the models. As users, they will share many common features, e.g. authentication during sign_in, change password, etc.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Buyer < User
  def buyer_specific_method_one
    ...
  end
end

class Seller < User
  def seller_specific_method_one
    ...
  end
end
```

And add a string field named 'type' to the user table. See [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance).

Comment: Ok, so I can store specific methods for each type of User Class. Am I also able to store the bank details in these methods and is it a better way than storing those details in the database? In my mind it makes sense to have those details in the database to query if needed. Thanks for your input @roob look forward to hearing your thoughts. :)

Comment: Regarding bank details, I would store it separately simply because I would like my users (especially buyers) to have more than one bank account :-) unless you are not allowed to store their bank details...

Comment: We don't store Buyers bank details, that goes through Stripe (similar to Paypal). We need to store bank details for Sellers so we can pay them for items they have sold. Currently we hold payment for an amount of time to ensure a safe transaction of goods for buyers. So we store bank details for Sellers to pay them that money manually later. We'll automate this all in the future. Thanks @Roob great input :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of options you can use. Not necessarily one, some combinations are possible:

**Factor out differences** (bank details?) **into separate models** with one-one relationships with `User`

- You can make them one-many later if you need to, one seller may provide info for multiple banks
- You do not restrict your users from being both buyer and a seller simultaneously (if you want)
- If these details are not needed on every single request, the performance penalty is not too big

[**Single Table Inheritance**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance)

- Alter the string column `user_type` to be just `type`, then make two more models **without a table** (`--no-migration`), inheriting not from `ActiveRecord::Base`, but from `User`, so they inherit its table for persistence
- Your `users` table will need to have all the columns from all subclasses
- Any `User` subclasses (like `Buyer`) will be defined as a `User` with certain `type` (`"Buyer"`)

[**Serialize attributes**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) that you'll be processing on app level only, not in the database

- You'll need to create a `text`-type column for each collection of serialized attributes that you want
- You'll only be restricted by the format of serializer, not database columns and types, it allows you to store arbitrary data there
- [You can define a custom serializer](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-write-custom-serializer-for-activerecord-number-serialize/) that outputs custom objects (maybe even models?)
- Be extra careful not to allow users to arbitrarily edit collections
- Make sure you only need serialized data from already loaded objects, contrary is a design flaw

Comment: Quick question @D-side it's still not 100% clear on how the two columns 'Sort Code' and 'Account Number' will be stored. For example Single table inheritance, where is the data actually stored?

Factor out differences and putting them in a separate model makes sense, but sure it would be a 0..1 relationship? Not every user would have the seller bank details model.

Thanks! :)

Comment: 1) It's stored in `users`. Even if only one subclass needs them, the entire table will need them. 2) One-to-one indicates the possibility. Association may be absent.

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify, I add two new columns into the `users` table. Those columns are `account_no` and `sort_code. I then specify the subclass `seller` in the `seller` model. I'm guessing it makes sense to only have a `seller`subclass, this being due to the fact `sellers` may want to buy something and in fact could be both `sellers` and `buyers`. Thanks @D-side you have been a lot of help :)